# How to make geom_smooth less dynamic

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

When generating smoothed plots with faceting in ggplot, if the range of the data changes from facet to facet the smoothing may acquire too many degress of freedom for the facets with less data.

For example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2) # ggplot2_2.2.1

set.seed(1234)
expand.grid(z = -5:2, x = seq(-5,5, len = 50)) %>%
  mutate(y = dnorm(x) + 0.4*runif(n())) %>% 
  filter(z <= x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess', span = 0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~ z)
```

generates the following:[image: faceted plot]
The z=-5 facet is fine, but as one moves to subsequent facets the smoothing seems to 'overfit'; indeed z=-1 already suffers from that, and in the last facet, z=2, the smoothed line fits the data perfectly. Ideally, what I would like is a less dynamic smoothing that for example always smooths about 4 points (or kernel smoothing with a fixed kernel).

The [following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925604/setting-a-unique-span-parameter-for-each-geom-smooth-on-a-multi-facet-ggplot) is related but perhaps more ambitious (in that it wants more control over `span`); here I want a *simpler* form of smoothing.

Comment: You could adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930704/r-nls-not-picking-up-additional-arguments-when-used-in-custom-function-in-geom) – which uses a custom smoothing function – to use a different function depending on number of data points, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved a few things around in your code to get this to work. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it's a simple way.

First we group by your z variable and then generate a number **span** that is small for large numbers of observations but large for small numbers. I guessed at `10/length(x)`. Perhaps there's some more statistically sound way of looking at it. Or perhaps it should be `2/diff(range(x))`. Since this is for your own visual smoothing, you'll have to fine tune that parameter yourself.

```
  expand.grid(z = -5:2, x = seq(-5,5, len = 50)) %>%    
    filter(z <= x) %>%
    group_by(z) %>% 
    mutate(y = dnorm(x) + 0.4*runif(length(x)),
           span = 10/length(x)) %>% 
    distinct(z, span)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 x 2
> # Groups:   z [8]
>       z      span
>   <int>     <dbl>
> 1    -5 0.2000000
> 2    -4 0.2222222
> 3    -3 0.2500000
> 4    -2 0.2857143
> 5    -1 0.3333333
> 6     0 0.4000000
> 7     1 0.5000000
> 8     2 0.6666667
> ```

---

### Update

The method I did have here was not working correctly. The best way to do this (and the most flexible way to do model-fitting in general) is to pre-compute it.

So we take our grouped dataframe with the computed **span**, fit a loess model to each group with the appropriate span, and then use `broom::augment` to form it back into a dataframe.

```
  library(broom)

  expand.grid(z = -5:2, x = seq(-5,5, len = 50)) %>%    
    filter(z <= x) %>%
    group_by(z) %>% 
    mutate(y = dnorm(x) + 0.4*runif(length(x)),
           span = 10/length(x)) %>% 
    do(fit = list(augment(loess(y~x, data = ., span = unique(.$span)), newdata = .))) %>%
    unnest()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 260 x 7
>        z    z1         x           y  span    .fitted    .se.fit
>    <int> <int>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
>  1    -5    -5 -5.000000 0.045482851   0.2 0.07700057 0.08151451
>  2    -5    -5 -4.795918 0.248923802   0.2 0.18835244 0.05101045
>  3    -5    -5 -4.591837 0.243720422   0.2 0.25458037 0.04571323
>  4    -5    -5 -4.387755 0.249378098   0.2 0.28132026 0.04947480
>  5    -5    -5 -4.183673 0.344429272   0.2 0.24619206 0.04861535
>  6    -5    -5 -3.979592 0.256269425   0.2 0.19213489 0.05135924
>  7    -5    -5 -3.775510 0.004118627   0.2 0.14574901 0.05135924
>  8    -5    -5 -3.571429 0.093698117   0.2 0.15185599 0.04750935
>  9    -5    -5 -3.367347 0.267809673   0.2 0.17593182 0.05135924
> 10    -5    -5 -3.163265 0.208380125   0.2 0.22919335 0.05135924
> # ... with 250 more rows
> ```

This has the side effect of duplicating the grouping column **z**, but it intelligently renames it to avoid name-collision, so we can ignore it. You can see that there are the same number of rows as the original data, and the original **x, y**, and **z** are there, as well as our computed **span**.

If you want to prove to yourself that it's really fitting each group with the right span, you can do something like:

```
  ... mutate(...) %>% 
    do(fit = (loess(y~x, data = ., span = unique(.$span)))) %>% 
    pull(fit) %>% purrr::map(summary)
```

That will print out the model summaries with the span included.

Now it's just a matter of plotting the augmented dataframe we just made, and manually reconstructing the smoothed line and confidence interval.

```
  ... %>%
    ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin = .fitted - 1.96*.se.fit, 
                    ymax = .fitted + 1.96*.se.fit), 
                alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(x, .fitted), color = "blue", size = 1) +
    facet_wrap(~ z)
```

[image]

Comment: I'd love to get something like this to work, but it seems to me that your technique is, in effect, simply omitting the `span` (which is the same as setting to 0.75). For example, rerun my code with the `span` omitted and you should get the same plot as your plot above.

Comment: @banbh, You appear to be correct. `stat_smooth` is actually ignoring all the arguments I put in `method.args`. I'll have to investigate.

Comment: I think I agree with this post (and with the link in my original post) that probably the most straightforward way is do as this post says (precompute and plot). The comment by @Lyngbakr is the only other approach I can think of, although it might make the code harder to follow.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply remove the `span` option (because 0.3 seems too granular) or use `lm` method to do polynomial fit.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2) # ggplot2_2.2.1

set.seed(1234)
expand.grid(z = -5:2, x = seq(-5,5, len = 50)) %>%
  mutate(y = dnorm(x) + 0.4*runif(n())) %>% 
  filter(z <= x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, 4)) +
  #geom_smooth(method = 'loess') +
  #geom_smooth(method = 'loess', span = 0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~ z)
```

Comment: The problem with removing the `span` argument (equivalent to increasing it to 0.75) is that it decreases the amount of smoothing in all facets. In fact one can see this happening with the `method = 'lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, 4)` too; for example increase the degree to 9 (from 4) and you get a plot similar to the plot in my original post. One way of rephrasing this is that `poly(x,4)` (and more-or-less, loess too) fixes the number of 'wiggles' the smooth curve can have. And while the number of wiggles may be right for the first facet (with lots of data and a wide range) it overfits the last.

Comment: I see.  So you want to use different smoothing parameter for each facet.  `geom_smooth` does not have that option as far as I know.  The argument `method.args` may have a chance but `loess` function does not seem to have a functionality to adjust parameters automatically based on the number of observation.  I could think of two approaches: Make predictive modelling outside the `geom_smooth` call and draw lines and ribbons mannually (as your link suggests) or write your own smoothing function (as a comment suggests).

Comment: You may be right; the approaches you mention may be the best way to proceed. The reason I posed the question is because I don't want to *arbitrarily* vary the `span` across facets, instead I want a smoothing method that is in a sense simpler; for example (speaking vaguely about "wiggles") I may want "no more than 1 wiggle per 1 unit in the x coordinate".

Answer (score 1):

Since I asked how to do kernel smoothing I wanted to provide an answer for *that*.

I'll start by just adding it as extra data to data frame and plotting that, much as the accepted answer does.

First here is the data and packages I'll be using (same as in my post):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2) # ggplot2_2.2.1

set.seed(1234)
expand.grid(z = -5:2, x = seq(-5,5, len = 50)) %>%
  mutate(y = dnorm(x) + 0.4*runif(n())) %>% 
  filter(z <= x) ->
  Z
```

Next here is the plot:

```
Z %>%
  group_by(z) %>%
  do(data.frame(ksmooth(.$x, .$y, 'normal', bandwidth = 2))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line(data = Z) +
  geom_line(color = 'blue', size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ z)
```

which simply uses `ksmooth` from base R. Note that it's quite simple to avoid the dynamic smoothing (making the bandwidth constant takes care of that). In fact, one can recover the a dynamic style smoothing (i.e., more like `geom_smooth`) as follows:

```
Z %>%
  group_by(z) %>%
  do(data.frame(ksmooth(.$x, .$y, 'normal', bandwidth = diff(range(.$x))/5))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line(data = Z) +
  geom_line(color = 'blue', size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ z)
```

I also followed the example in https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt/blob/master/R/geom_xspline.r to turn this idea into an actual `stat_` and `geom_` as follows:

```
geom_ksmooth <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "ksmooth",
                         position = "identity", na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = NA,
                         inherit.aes = TRUE,
                         bandwidth = 0.5, ...) {
  layer(
    geom = GeomKsmooth,
    mapping = mapping,
    data = data,
    stat = stat,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(bandwidth = bandwidth,
                  ...)
  )
}

GeomKsmooth <- ggproto("GeomKsmooth", GeomLine,
                       required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                       default_aes = aes(colour = "blue", size = 1, linetype = 1, alpha = NA)
)

stat_ksmooth <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "line",
                         position = "identity", na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
                         bandwidth = 0.5, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatKsmooth,
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    geom = geom,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(bandwidth = bandwidth,
                  ...
    )
  )
}

StatKsmooth <- ggproto("StatKsmooth", Stat,
                       required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                       compute_group = function(self, data, scales, params,
                                                bandwidth = 0.5) {
                         data.frame(ksmooth(data$x, data$y, kernel = 'normal', bandwidth = bandwidth))
                       }
)
```

(Note that I have a very poor understanding of the above code.) But now we can do:

```
Z %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_ksmooth(bandwidth = 2) +
  facet_wrap(~ z)
```

And the smoothing is not dynamic, as I originally wanted.

I do wonder if there is a simpler way, though.